# Cocoapods - Found multiple specifications warning

Tags: cocoapods

On `pod install`, I am getting warning like `Found multiple specifications for "<Pod Name>"`

It means that I have multiple `Podspecs` in this directory `~/cocoapods/repo`

Example Podfile:

```rb
source '<Private Podspec>'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'SDKDemo' do
  use_frameworks!    
  pod '<Pod Name>'
end
```

My question is that

1. which Podspec will be used when installing pod.
2. If Podspec is taken from `<Private Podspec>`, How it will work in this case

```rb
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source '<Private Podspec>'
```

I came to conclusion like order of source will affect deciding the Podspec. But I want to clarify this.

Answer (score 9):

I had both `source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'` and `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'` included in `Podfile`

```
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

After removing `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'` the warnings gone.

Comment: Where did you have both files, please write file location.

Comment: They were in Podfile

Answer (score 7):

On my side, that approach (changing the order of the sources) never worked.

I needed to **specify** the source for my private **pod** in order to make it work.
The reason is that *my private* **pod** registered in *my private* **specs repo** has the same name than another one registered in the **public cocoapods specs repo**.

i.e.:

```rb
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' # public cocoapods specs repo
source 'https://github.com/{:user}/specs.git' # my private specs repo

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'MyAppTarget' do
  use_frameworks!
  # any other public pod ...
  pod 'PrivatePod', :source => 'https://github.com/{:user}/specs.git'
end
```

This is what solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

In Cocoapods version 1.8.x, I fixed this issue by changing the source from
`source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'` to `source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'` in `Podfile`

It also depends on the errors that you receive. It is always useful to check in `~/.cocoapods/repos` folder to see what repos are causing the warnings. It could be that you have two instances of your private podspec in `~/.cocoapods/repos`. In my case I had this

```
[!] Found multiple specifications for `GoogleUtilities (6.2.4)`:
- /Users/hientran/.cocoapods/repos/master/Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.2.4/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json
- /Users/hientran/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/6.2.4/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json
```

Simply remove master repo and I've never seen that warning since then

```
pod repo remove master
```

Answer (score 1):

The CocoaPods Guides have the answer:

> The order of the sources is relevant. CocoaPods will use the highest version of a Pod of the first source which includes the Pod (regardless whether other sources have a higher version).

Whichever source you enter first will be the first source CocoaPods will look for the pod.

For Question #1: Since you have `source '<Private Podspec>'` first, that's what it will use.

For Question#2: Since you have `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'` first, that's what it will use.

https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#tab_source

Comment: This is totally not the right answer to the asekd problem. The correct answer was already given and upvoted. (Removing multiple sources)

Comment: This is the only one who actually *read* the whole question. The OP didn't ask for the ways to solve the problem, but the mechanism behind cocoapods.